# ObjectOutput and ObjectInputStream - special characters

Tags: java, sockets, encoding, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

My Android application receives text messages using a `BroadcastReceiver`. Then it uses `ObjectOutputStream` to send it to my server, which receives it using, of cource, `ObjectInputStream`. If I print the message in the Android application and view it in LogCat, the received message is shown correctly. All characters are showing correctly. But when it is sent over these object streams, it gets changed and doesn't show up correctly any more. All special characters are replaced with question marks.

For example, I got a message with a thumb up icon. I could see it as the icon in LogCat and in Android's text message software, but my server received it as a question mark and it was saved as two question marks in the MySQL database.

How do I handle those with these object output and input streams?

I don't send the messages as text but as objects. I have a class called `SMSMessage` that contains all the information of the message. I sent this using the socket.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"? Ääkköset?

Comment: I mean characters such as the thumb up icon I used as an example in the post. Sorry, I would post it here but it appears as a square.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an encoding issue. Characters are usually converted to a question mark or a box (or a question mark inside a box) if they can't be represented in the particular encoding. You can see this in action by creating a file containing letters "äöå" in ISO-8859-15 encoding and opening it as UTF-8 in a text editor.

However ObjectStreams shouldn't corrupt the encoding like that as far as I remember. You could try using other streams besides ObjectStreams (I assume Android isn't limited to them) and specify a suitable encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16) to see if it comes through correctly.